# Not getting all the information when scraping bet365.com

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy, screen-scraping

I am having problem when trying to scrape https://www.bet365.com/ using `urllib.request` and `BeautifulSoup`.
The problem is, the code below doesn't get all the information on the page, for example players' names don't appear. Maybe another framework or configuration to extract the information?

My code is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
url = "https://www.bet365.com/"
try:
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
except:
    print("An error occured.")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
soup = str(soup)
```

Comment: Information isn't always all contained in the initial HTML response. When loading the page on a browser, are there additional requests after the initial load that contains the information you need? (use a browser like chrome and the developer tools to analyse)

Comment: No additional requests after loading @FraggaMuffin, even if I use element inspector in Chrome I can find all information I want. Do you know any tool which could take advantage of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source code for the page in question it looks like essentially all of the data is populated by Javascript.  BeautifulSoup isn't a headless client, it's just something that downloads and parses HTML, so anything that's populated with Javascript it can't see.  You'd need a headless browser like selenium to scrape something like that.

Comment: I got you, but I have never been able to get selenium working in this website, I don't know wheter to ignorance of selenium. Could you attach some brief code about how you would solve it using selenium or another tool?

Comment: Maybe they don't want it to be scraped.  It's fairly easy to make sites that can't be scraped by any readily available tools.

Comment: So, although I can get the information uising element inspector in chrome manually, it doesn't imply that any available tool can get this information autommatically, doesn't it?

Comment: That's getting somewhat removed from the original question.  Why don't you post a new question with your sample selenium implementation, highlighting where it fails?

Comment: I will do it, but my implementation looks like the one that Khaled Koubaa has attached.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use selenium instead of requests, along with Beautifulsoup as well.

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://www.bet365.com"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"the_path_of_driver")

driver.get(url)

driver.maximize_window() #optional, if you want to maximize the browser
driver.implicitly_wait(60) ##Optional, Wait the loading if error

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')  #get the soup
```

Comment: Does it work for you? Have you tested it? Cause I have been trying to test it and it doesn't finish loading the page, it gets stuck. I am using Firefox webdriver but I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: what do you need to scrape exactly ? odds movement ? just events names ?

Comment: events names and its own odds

Comment: I think bet365 prevent loading the website on webdrivers, you can scrape data you need (and more) from oddsportal